# Distinguish between HTC Vive controller grip buttons in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, input, htc-vive, steam-vr

In Unity, I can check for grip button presses via the SteamVR API like so:

```
if(controller.GetPressDown(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Grip)) { ... }
```

This results in either `true` or `false` so I can only check if any grip button was pressed but not specifically which one.

---

For Unity's Input API the documentation states [[1](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OpenVRControllers.html)]:

> The grip trigger differs between platforms:
>
> - The HTC Vive controllers each have two grip buttons but both map to
>     the same axis. The value for these buttons is 0.0 when not pressed and
>     1.0 when pressed (intermediate values between 0.0 and 1.0 are not possible).

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OpenVRControllers.html

In this case it is again not possible to differ between the two grip buttons.

Is there any way in Unity to check which one of the grip buttons of a HTC Vive controller is pressed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This seems intentional because the grip buttons are supposed to be indistinguishable (depending on whether you hold the controller in the left or the right hand you can only press one of them anyway).